# After partial page load using ajax how to initialise/attach all javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which call some event binders during page load. There is a link on page that load another page in DIV. Problem is already binded events are not available for newly created elements during ajax call. Please help.

Below is sample javascript I am using

```
//Javascript start
addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    init();
});
function init() {
 _$("body").addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
        ...
    });
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
        ...
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
        ...
    });
        document.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
        ...
    });
}
```

USING Jquery 1.5

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why don't you use jQuery events?

More info about event binding in jQuery can be found in this article: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be using jQuery's own event attachers:

```
_$(function(){
//Code below will be run on load, jQuery takes care of that for you.

    _$("body").on('touchmove', function(event){
       ...
    });
    // and so on
});
```

`on()` attaches listeners to dinamically future created elements. You should also check if the events are triggered or bubbled properly to the object you attached them.

Comment: what about other events like window and document. My application is using jQuery 1.5

Comment: For 1.5, I'd revert to `.live('touchmove',handler)`. Do however update your jQuery to save some of the load and headaches.

Comment: Also, `$(window)` and `$(document)` should give you the right environment for the rest of your events. Still make sure those events are triggered that way, multi-platform-wise, otherwise you should maybe try a different approach (ie. via plugins).

Answer (score 0):

After every page load initialize the events.

So bind events in the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)